# Evenly cropping of an image from both side using imagemagick .net

Tags: imagemagick, image-resizing, magick.net

I am using image magick for .net to cropping and resizing the images. But the problem with the library is that it only crop the bottom of the image. Isn't there any way by means which we can crop it evenly from both up and down or left and right?

**Edited question :**

```
  MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(width, height);
  size.IgnoreAspectRatio = maintainAspectRatio;
  imgStream.Crop(size);
```

Comment: It will help if you add a code sample to demonstrate what you are doing.

Comment: Yes this is possible and easy to do. What have you tried?

Comment: @emcconville I have edited the question. This only crop the bottom part of the image. Can you please tell me how to do for both the side?

Comment: @dlemstra i have edited the question. Kindly look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Crop will always use the specified width and height in Magick.NET/ImageMagick so there is no need to set `size.IgnoreAspectRatio`. If you want to cut out a specific area in the center of your image you should use another overload of Crop that also has a Gravity as an argument:

```cs
imgStream.Crop(width, height, Gravity.Center);
```

Comment: can you please also help me with this problem also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701190/apply-watermark-on-image-using-imagemagick-net-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

If the `size` variable is an instance of `MagickGeometry`, than there should be an `X` & `Y` offset property. I'm not familiar with [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), but I would imagine it would be something like...

```cs
MagickGeometry size = new MagickGeometry(width, height);
size.IgnoreAspectRatio = maintainAspectRatio;
// Adjust geometry offset to center of image (same as `-gravity Center`)
size.Y = imgStream.Height / 2 - height / 2;
size.X = imgStream.Width / 2 - width / 2;
imgStream.Crop(size);
```