# GIF image loses its animation in Magick.net

Tags: magick.net, imagemagick.net

I am reading a GIF image and creating the ImageMagick object in C#. Then I write the same image to the output. In the output I get a static image without animation.

```
               MagickImage image = new MagickImage(ImagePath); 
               Byte[] buffer = image.ToByteArray();                                         
               HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";                                 
               HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);     
               HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 200;
```

Comment: as a side note: why do you call `image.ToByteArray()` twice? save it as a variable for performance.

Comment: This code was just to test this behaviour. But anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A MagickImage is a single image. When you read a .gif file you will only get the first frame of that animation. If you want to preserve the animation you should create a MagickImageCollection instead.