# C# program that overlays an image and saves the new image

Tags: c#

I'm fairly new at C# but want to make a program which imports a background image then a partially transparent image and combines the two into a new image. Then the image is saved. How would I do this?

Comment: Use ImageMagick, some sample code can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31701190/apply-watermark-on-image-using-imagemagick-net-in-c-sharp

Comment: Note: this happens to have a good answer at the linked duplicate, but this question is too broad for this site. Ordinarily, it would just be closed as too broad. Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).